# Shiny: use shinyjs to fetch cookie data

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I want to fetch cookie data from my Shiny app using shinyjs. I have created a cookie, "samplecookie=testval"; and I want to be able to retrieve the value of samplecookie. I use the below javascript function (where I pass the cookieName and it returns the corresponding value).

```
function fetchCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)==" ") c = c.substring(1,c.length);
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return      c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}   
return "No such cookie";
```

Below is the javascript code in the shiny app

```
jsCode<-'shinyjs.tstfunc=
    function (name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)==" ") c = c.substring(1,c.length);
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return      c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
return "No such cookie";
}   
}' 

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(mainPanel(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode)
)))

server <- function(input, output)
  {
    observe({
    x=js$tstfunc("samplecookie")
    print(x)
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I am expecting that when I pass "samplecookie" as a parameter to the tstfunc() function, it should print "testval" on the console. But every time I keep getting a NULL value returned. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm the author of shinyjs. You cannot use it like that to pass values from JS to R. The only way to pass a value from JS to R is to use inputs. In JavaScript you'd have to call the `Shiny.onInputChange()` function, and in R you need to add an observe/reactive statement that listens to that input being changed.

[Read this page to learn about passing values from JS to R](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/message-javascript-to-r)

The code you provide is a bit weird and hard to read so here's a simple example of how to do this. This code simply asks JavaScript to pass the current time to R, it's simple but it shows how to do this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.gettime = function(params) {
  var time = Date();
  Shiny.onInputChange("jstime", time);
}' 

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = "gettime")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  js$gettime()

  observe({
    cat(input$jstime)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @daattali any plans to extend `shinyjs` to support returning arguments in casual way? It would be very handy, indeed.

Comment: @AdamB do you mean in a way such that you can just `return` from javascript and shiny will receive that value? If that's what you mean, then that is not possible and I don't see how it can ever be possible (I may be wrong, but I don't think this sort of interaction can be supported)